# Why can't I delete my account on some Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts

If I visit some Stack Exchange sites that are under my *Accounts* section in my profile, my link options look like this:

[image]

However, on some Stack Exchange sites my link options look like this:

[image]

I have a site listed under my accounts (Skeptics.SE) which I want to delete since I don't use it, but unfortunately the *delete* link is not available to do so. So my questions are:

- Why can't I delete it on some sites?
- Why is there an inconsistency in the first place?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/140505):

> **If your account has never voted or posted a question or answer more than once**, you should see a self-delete option on your user page next to the edit link

The accounts that don't have a delete link are for the accounts that have voted or posted more than once.

Comment: Oh no, the account in question just has a lousy extra vote. Looks like I will be filling out the form. Thanks for the link, I don't know how I missed finding it when searching.

Comment: I get the following error on the linked form page *"User Profile Link should be of the form http://stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<display-name>"* I want to delete this account though http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/10831/cryptic how can I make sure that by entering in my SO profile that they don't accidentally delete that one. I would die if that happened. I know I can specify it in reason, but as the action is irreversible I want to make sure no accidents can happen. Call me paranoid =oP

Comment: @crypticツ - What site are you filling the form on? You should be doing so on skeptics, not SO.